# TFS Alerts not sending when Task is linked to Change

Tags: tfs

We have Alerts set up in our environment to notify developers when a task is created for them.

[image: Current Alert Filters]

These Alerts seem to work fine when a Task is created by itself.  However, if one of our Promotion Managers creates a Task by linking it to a Change Item then the Alert doesn't work.

For the time being I've asked the Promotion Managers to create the Tasks without linking them to a Parent ID and then link it afterwards but this is obviously not ideal.  Does anyone know how I could update my Alert Filters to allow the Alerts to flow again?

Addition Information [edit]:

We're using TFS 2015 Update 1

What I mean by "creates a Task by linking it to a Change Item" I mean that the Work Item is created as a child Task to the Change Work Item.

You go into the Change Work Item and under the "All Work Items Links" tab you create a new Task Work Item.  This links the Task to the Change.

Comment: What's that mean for "`creates a Task by linking it to a Change Item`"? What's tfs version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to fix my problem how I wanted to, I was able to figure out a work around that allowed my Alerts to perform as they used to.  This work around adds a few extra steps to the Work Item creation but at least the Alerts are working.

The old way:

- Open up a Change Work Item and under the "All Work Items Links" tab,
  select New and create a new Task Work Item from there.  This auto-links the Work Items together.

The work around:

- Create a new Task Work Item (Team > New Work Item > Task).  Once created, go to the "Relations" tab and select "Link to" with a Link Type of "Parent".  The Work Item ID in the Link details area will be the Change Work Item ID.

For some reason, creating the Task Work Item without a parent right from the start, allows my Alerts to fire with no issues.  I wish I understood why but my team is happy with the work around so I'll take the small victory.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using TFS 2015,

Based on your description if you want to the team members receive the alerts when a work item is changed, then you can create a Team alert : `A work item in this team project is changed`

Thus when link tasks to the work items which you have set alerts for them, then the alert will be triggered.

[image]

Comment: @V. Shoulak Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?

Comment: I edited my description above.  I have not found a solution as of yet.

Comment: @V.Shoulak You can try to combine the alerts, create another alert:  `A new work item is created in this team project `, thus the team member will receive the alerts once a new work items is created within the team project. And once lined to the changed work item, they will also receive the changed alerts.

Comment: I've played around with some other alerts.  I'm able to make an alert that allows the team members to be notified once a task is created but since the tasks could sit in the "New" state for a month or more before they become active it's not ideal.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: No.  I've asked my team to go about creating the tasks in a different way so that the alerts work as they're supposed to.